# Convert RDD[Map[String,Double]] to RDD[(String,Double)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I did some calculation and returned my values in a RDD containing scala map and now I want to remove this map and want to collect all keys values in a RDD.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `mapRDD.flatMap(_.values)` ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens: I think he wants the keys as well as the values in his result, thus my answer.

Comment: Yes Kim, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call flatMap with the identity function to 'flatten' the structure of your RDD.

```
rdd.flatMap(identity)
```

Comment: Awesome Kim, in a 1 hit I got what I wanted.

Comment: Kim when I save this RDD as a text file I get like this -> 

(Key,Value)

Can I save into file without these brackets .

And also can we change this comma and put some other delimiter like tab.

Comment: @KSHITIJKULSHRESTHA: that's an entirely separate question. you should ask a new question and post your code, but might be a good idea to do some of your own research first.

Comment: Did posted as a question, yes you are right let me research and then come to you.